# how to add a <br /> to an asp.net placeholder

Tags: asp.net

If I have an asp.net web page with placeholders, what is the simplest way to wrap a line break 

 into a control that I can pass to the Add function of the placeholder?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could add it as an `HtmlGenericControl`:

```
yourPlaceholder.Controls.Add(new HtmlGenericControl("br"));
```

Comment: But this will render: <br runat="server"></br>

Comment: One issue with this is it renders two <br> tags. You can see another post about this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493586/htmlgenericcontrolbr-rendering-twice.

Answer (score 11):

Or use a Literal Control (`new LiteralControl("<br />")`)

Comment: 1+ for generating less HTML in browser

Answer (score 4):

Just use literalcontrol

```
yourPlaceholder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"))
```