# HtmlGenericControl("br") rendering twice

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, htmlgenericcontrol

I'm adding some content to a given web page from code behind. When I want to add a break after some text, I try to do that this way:

```
pDoc.Controls.Add(New Label With {.Text = "whatever"})
pDoc.Controls.Add(New HtmlGenericControl("br"))
```

,where pDoc is the `Panel` in which I'm adding the content. But it adds two `br` tags into the final HTML.

I've avoid this behaviour this way:

```
pDoc.Controls.Add(New Label With {.Text = "whatever" & "<br />"})
```

Anyway, I'm so curious and I want to know why

```
pDoc.Controls.Add(New HtmlGenericControl("br"))
```

is acting that way. I also think my approach is not too fancy.

Regards,

Comment: Are you sure it is rendering `<br><br>` not `<br></br>`?

Comment: yeah, he is right it is rendering <br><br>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some testing it looks like the reason is that `HtmlGenericControl` doesn't support *self closing*. On server side the `HtmlGenericControl("br")` is treated as:

```
<br runat="server"></br>
```

There is no `</br>` tag in HTML, so the browser shows it as there are two `<br />` tags. Nice way out of this is to create `HtmlGenericSelfCloseControl` like this (sorry for C# code but you should have no issue with rewritting this in VB.NET):

```
public class HtmlGenericSelfCloseControl : HtmlGenericControl
{
    public HtmlGenericSelfCloseControl()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public HtmlGenericSelfCloseControl(string tag)
        : base(tag)
    {
    }

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.TagLeftChar + this.TagName);
        Attributes.Render(writer);
        writer.Write(HtmlTextWriter.SelfClosingTagEnd);
    }

    public override ControlCollection Controls
    {
        get { throw new Exception("Self closing tag can't have child controls"); }
    }

    public override string InnerHtml
    {
        get { return String.Empty; }
        set { throw new Exception("Self closing tag can't have inner content"); }
    }

    public override string InnerText
    {
        get { return String.Empty; }
        set { throw new Exception("Self closing tag can't have inner text"); }
    }
}
```

And use it instead:

```
pDoc.Controls.Add(New Label With {.Text = "whatever"})
pDoc.Controls.Add(New HtmlGenericSelfCloseControl("br"))
```

As a simpler alternative (if you have reference to the `Page`) you can try using `Page.ParseControl`:

```
pDoc.Controls.Add(New Label With {.Text = "whatever"})
pDoc.Controls.Add(Page.ParseControl("br"))
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to inherit from `HtmlControl`? Then you'd just need the constructor, and possibly an override of `RenderAttributes` if you wanted an XHTML-style self-closing tag.

Comment: @RichardDeeming Most probably yes, I just had this code written some time ago in one of my projects and I pasted it without considering for refactorization.

Comment: Page.ParseControl("br") does not work for me. 
Page.ParseControl("<br/>") does work.

Answer (score 27):

Actually you can use;

```
pDoc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
```

Whereas `new HtmlGenericControl("br")` adds two `<br>`, this will only add `<br/>` tag to your HTML so that you just have 1 space line.
In this picture I added those breaks with that code block.

[image]

Also similar question here: [Server control behaving oddly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7526985/1847645)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works fine. I'm upvoting, but not marking as the correct answer due I consider the previous one more specific to my question.